# Two method for UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

We need to set a `UIButton` with 2 methods, the first one is when you touch it (down and up) you get one action , but when you long press it, you get another one.

For example, to get data about it when you long click, and when regular click , another thing.

How can i achieve this with UIButton ?

```
            UIButton *CAT = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            CAT.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
            CAT.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            [CAT addTarget:self action:@selector(newcat:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I have started with adding it a gesture with this

```
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
        [CAT addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

But this triggered only when you take off your finger .
i want it to be triggered while my finger is still there after 1-2 seconds .
Can i do that? and can i adjust the time required for it to trigger ?

Comment: my intuition would be to subclass `UIButton` and add long press and short press events, using `NSTimer` and the information from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events

Comment: thanks a lot,  see my edit, it actually works ,but not as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this is normal method**

```
     UIButton *CAT = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CAT.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
        CAT.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [CAT addTarget:self action:@selector(newcat:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = 
 [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 5;   // set the time interval

[longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
[CAT addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];

[self.view addsubview: CAT];
```

**longpress action method**

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
 // do long press action
}
```

**normal action method**

```
-(void) newcat:(id)sender

{
  // do normal action here
 }
```

Comment: thanks as i wrote i did that,but the problem is that the long press is occur only when you take your finger off the screen, i want it to trigered while my finger is still in there ,after 1 second .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the event `UIControlEventTouchDown`, use delay time for **long press** and you must deal with `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`. good luck!